# jshint - ignore node_modules directory

Tags: jshint, eslint

I am simply running:

```
$> jshint .
```

which looks through my project's directory for .js files, but it is also looking into the node_modules directory which has a shit-ton of .js files that I don't really want to know about.

I might mention that eslint works out of the box to ignore the node_modules directory.

is there a way to run .jshint with a flag to ignore the node_modules directory?

for example

```
$> jshint . --ignore ./node_modules
```

?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To ignore the node_modules folder using `JSHint`, this seems to work best

in your `package.json` file at the root of your project:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "jshint": "jshint --exclude 'node_modules/**/*' ."
  }
}
```

now you can run this at the command line

```bash
npm run jshint
```

and you won't forget the syntax because you have documented it for yourself

You can also use `.jshintignore`:

```
node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 7):

According to https://jshint.com/docs/cli/#ignoring-files you can also use the `.jshintignore` file.

Just add:

```
node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for ignoring the `node_modlues` directory from the `.jshintignore` file is:

```
node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .jshintrc file in the root directory of your project with the following config :

```
{
   node: true
}
```

For a full list of options you can look [here](http://jshint.com/docs/options/)

Comment: thanks I have that, the syntax is correct, but it didn't seem to work, the answer I just created works for sure though

Comment: This is no longer correct - probably since before 2015, but certainly not in 2023.